# Socket или Long polling в андроид ява

Tags: java, android, сокет, long-poll

Всем привет. В приложении хочу сделать чат администрации. Для этого придется использовать либо Сокет либо Long polling. В приложении не малую роль играет фактор экономии трафика. Так вот что будеть меньше трафика кушать? Socket or Long polling?

Comment: Оба будут кушать батарею. Используйте лучше Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Оба часто используются, судя по вопросы хорошо подходит Firebase, RealTImeDatabase + Auth

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei  Я прочитал о них обоих и понял что это крутая штука но не понял этот сервис бесплатный?

Comment: есть ограничения, для бесплатного использования. Можно хранить 20M сообщений и передавать примерно 200M сообщений в месяц. Я думаю для чата хватит вполне. Вы зайдите на оф сайт там всё есть

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Спасибо так и сделаю